# Angular 2 checkbox params.setValue is not a function error?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GridOptions, RowNode } from 'ag-grid/main';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';


@Component({
    selector: 'qrp-drop-down-selector',
    template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="params.value" style="margin-top: -6px;" (change)="params.setValue($event.target.checked ? true : null)">
    `
})
export class QrpDropdownEditorComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    private params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

I created this kind of component. But when I put the checkbox error **self.context.params.setValue is not a function** In what exactly was I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is looking for an object with the setValue() method. It can't find it. Try something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'qrp-drop-down-selector',
    template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="params.value" style="margin-top: -6px;" (change)="setValue($event.target.checked ? true : null)">
    `
})
export class QrpDropdownEditorComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    private params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    setValue(val: boolean) {
       this.params = val;
    }
}
```